# What are the major new features in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on rails 2.3.4 . As rails new version rails 3 has arrived , I want to know which are the major changes rails3 has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/2/5/rails-3-0-beta-release/

> There’s plenty to get excited about
>   here. A few of the headliner features
>   are:

- Brand new router with an emphasis on RESTful declarations
- New Action Mailer API modelled after Action Controller (now without the agonizing pain of sending multipart messages!)
- New Active Record chainable query language built on top of relational algebra
- Unobtrusive JavaScript helpers with drivers for Prototype, jQuery, and more coming (end of inline JS)
- Explicit dependency management with Bundler

[My Five Favorite Things About Rails
   3](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2009/my-five-favorite-things-about-rails-3/)

[Google "rails 3"](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=rails+3)

Answer (score 6):

Did you check the [release notes](http://guides.rails.info/3_0_release_notes.html)?

If you're looking for more Rails 3 info, you could [start here](http://www.rubyinside.com/rails-3-0-beta-links-2966.html).

Answer (score 1):

[From rubyonrails.org blog](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/2/5/rails-3-0-beta-release/)

- Brand new router with an emphasis on RESTful declarations
- New Action Mailer API modelled after Action Controller (now without the agonizing pain of sending multipart messages!)
- New Active Record chainable query language built on top of relational algebra
- Unobtrusive JavaScript helpers with drivers for Prototype, jQuery, and more coming (end of inline JS)
- Explicit dependency management with Bundler

Answer (score 1):

[yehuda Katz](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2009/my-five-favorite-things-about-rails-3/) features list on rails 3 will give and here is the [list](http://railsnotes.com/rails-3/) on rails-3 to learn

Comment: Thank you every one to help me knowing the new points added and link support